Route calculation API with Elevation Considerations
I'm need calculator like on roadrunnerautotransport.com.
For example routes from Denver to Los Angeles and back has differences in elevation.
In the screenshots below, you can see how the price varies depending on the direction.
Does anyone have recommendations for APIs or other tools that could provide information with some  coefficient or other info to calculate it?
If a similar topic has been discussed before, please throw me a link.
Denver - LA
LA - Denver
I've try register in ship.cars but they're updating their API and it isn't available now.
Google Maps, AWS location services and others don't provide (I didn't find) some info to calculate some similar differences.
